# Having problem in installing httpd

Tags: 20.04

When I use `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y httpd` command it is asking as in below

```
Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
```

How do I proceed with it in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install -y httpd  This is the command what is with the RUN?

Comment: @Terrance I assume OP is using Docker.

Comment: @Kulfy Would have been nice if they stated that so that I didn't waste my time asking questions on something that I don't use or know.

Comment: Same for me waste time

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qqy httpd
```